# Spinner value is not storing correctly

Tags: android, database, spinner

I am trying to store my values in a database, all are storing correctly except the value of spinner.

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12fqH.png)

[image: image 1]

[2nd image is my database values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ8Bc.png)

[image: image 2]

**This is my code, you can check.. i used adapter to store items .**

```
package com.example.sourabhkumargupta.blood_donor;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class signup_form extends AppCompatActivity {

     private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
     Spinner dropdown;
     Button form_submit;
     EditText name,email,password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup_form);
        dropdown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dropdown);
        String[] items = new String[]{"select Blood Group","A-","A+","B-","B+"};
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,items);
        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);


        form_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.form_submit);
        final DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        form_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean result = databaseHelper.insertData(name.getText().toString(),email.getText().toString(),
                    dropdown.toString(),password.getText().toString());
            if(result==true)
                Toast.makeText(signup_form.this,"Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            else
                Toast.makeText(signup_form.this,"Fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please paste code here with proper formatting.

Comment: Please provide your code as text and not as an image, most of us won't rewrite it or use an OCR.

Comment: ok m trying but its showing too long

Comment: use dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: plz check my code.. now i Updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, to store current selected value from spinner, you should replace `dropdown.toString()` to `dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString()` instead.

Comment: tried , but same result.. wait m tring to paste full code

Comment: Do you try to clear current user_detail table then apply the above line of code?

Comment: dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString() its working .. thanks.

Comment: @SaurabhGupta --- Glad to here that. FYI when you call dropdown.toString();. Because Spinner class do not override toString method so it will revoke toString method of its parent (in this case android.view.View). You can go there and read the implementation. The incorrect value that you got is result returned from toString method.

Answer (score 0):

> dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString()

is Ideal solution for your issue if its not working then please share code how you are binding data in to your drop down(Spinner)

Comment: Can you please show following toast inside "form_submit" onclick
e
                Toast.makeText(signup_form.this,dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);